# How does spot lamp radius affect the cone size

Tags: lighting

I noticed that by increasing the radius of a spot lamp the size of the light cone also changes, even if the cone size of the spot light symbol doesn't change.

What is the mathematical realtionship between the radius of the spot lamp and the light cone size?

Answer (score 2):

There is no relationship.  The lamp's radius, as described in [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/lights/light_object.html#spot-light) only affects the softness of shadows and highlights.  Also, the size of the light cone should not change when you change the radius.  What version of Blender are you using?

Here's an example of spot size change not changing light cone in 3.1.2:

[image: example of spotlight radius growth]

Comment: It does, try scaling by a factor of ten and you will see a change in the area where the light is hittting the plane

Comment: If I scale that spot's radius by 10 the plane will fall inside the sphere.

Comment: Well of cousre you don't have to increase the radius exactly by a factor of 10... What I wanted to say is that the light falls outside of the cone if you increase the radius of the lamp